# Connect Div Tags when Scrolling Offscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make div tags connect to each other when scrolling on screen, but I want one of the divs to stay onscreen when it hits the top and the other div keeps moving. When the still moving div gets offscreen, I want the div that stayed onscreen to move off with it. That probably makes no sense, but I made a short animation of my goal. You can see that [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oghsn9ss3soxcx4/Animation%20Goal.mp4?dl=0). It might be a bit difficult, but thanks for replying.

Comment: assign an event to window `scroll`, check if that element is about to move out of view port , add a css class to the element which makes the div look fixed.

Comment: Thank you. Should be simple enough.